# Event onclick in my controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, scope

I wrote thi code in my controllers:

```
$('#categoryId').on('click', function(event){       
        $scope.items = $scope.getUpdatedItems ();
        console.log('Items  ',$scope.items );
    });
```

In my directives I have this:

```
....
scope.$watch('items', function(items){
  console.log('Directives - Items  ',items );
....
```

The problem is that I never enter in the $watch declared in my directives.

Somebody can help me..
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [$watch'ing for data changes in an Angular directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980896/watching-for-data-changes-in-an-angular-directive)

Comment: have you tried $scope.$apply(), because you are running code outside of angular context

Comment: why don't think of `ng-click`?

Comment: @user880386 check I've added an answer..with a valid way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mixed up jQuery with AngularJS that will mess up with the digest cycle on angular. Angular did provided its own directive to handle such activity like in your case you could us `ng-click` directive, this will call the mentioned function inside `ng-click` attribute value on click on that element.

**Markup**

```
<button type="categoryId" ng-click="updateAllItems()"></button>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.updateAllItems = function(){       
    $scope.items = $scope.getUpdatedItems ();
    console.log('Items  ',$scope.items );
});
```

Above code will call `updateAllItems` function which resides inside controller & then `$scope.items` will get updated. And then you watch inside directive will get call.