# Directive call to controller function not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I base my code on the example in the answer of [$watch'ing for data changes in an Angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980896/watching-for-data-changes-in-an-angular-directive)
No error message is displayed, bu method 'fromUpdated' is not being called.

Here is a part of the directive's javascript:

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ctrlFromupdated: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.ctrlFromupdated({ from: new Date() });
```

Here is a part of the HTML code

```
 <mydirective id="dateFrom" ng-ctrl-fromupdated="fromUpdated(args)" ...
```

Here is the method in controller:

```
$scope.fromUpdated = function (args) {
    var from = args.from;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this :

```
<mydirective id="dateFrom" ctrlFromupdated="fromUpdated(args)" ...
```