# Need to trigger direcitve , inside watch from a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added some validations in directive ,now i need to call this directive every time there is a change (by using watch).So basically triggering directive on an event inside a controller in angularjs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980896/watching-for-data-changes-in-an-angular-directive
Check this answer