# getting control scope values changes in injected directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am having my own directive called `myDir`. I want to import this into my angular sample and i want to watch my sample side values in my `myDir`.

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <my-dir values='val' ></my-dir>
      </div>
       angular.module('myApp', ['demo'])
            .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.click =function (args)
            {
                $scope.val = "changes".
            }
            })
```

my another module looks like below

```
    var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
      demo.directive('myDir', function($parse) {
      return {
            restrict: "E",

        template: 'template',
        link:
                function(scope, element, attrs){
               scope.$watch(attrs["val"], fucntion(newval,oldval){console.log(newval,oldval)})
            }
}
});
```

in above i am not able to console log my value changes. I want to see **val** changes in **myDir** directive

Comment: use different variable name other than new in **function(new,old)**

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled *function*. Also, don't use [reserved](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) words like 'new' as a param.

Replace

```
fucntion(new,old){console.log(new,old)}
```

With

```
function(n,o){console.log(n,o)}
```

Then, 
You also need to pass the value from the scope to the directive correctly and then deep check it in the watch (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980896/watching-for-data-changes-in-an-angular-directive))

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
      demo.directive('myDir', function($parse) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            val: '='
        },
        template: 'template',
        link:
            function(scope, element, attrs){
           scope.$watch('val', function(n,o){console.log(n,o)}, true)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: my problem is watch not triggering here, since m not able to get the changes.

Comment: @Kbvin updated my answer. Also make sure you have define the ng-app="myApp" in the view

Comment: is this possible to achieve without defining  val: '=' ?

Comment: it should work with scope.$watch(scope.val, func..), try that