# AngularJS isolated directive watch for changes for all of the two way data bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, listener, directive

In AngularJS, when something change in parent, the child binds the new change,
automatically. However this awesome process is being done only in the HTML file,
but not in the JS file.

Sometimes, if not always, we would like to acheive the same thing also in JS files.

Directive is getting initialized via the JS file, like this:

```
// statusBadge.js directive
app.directive("statusBadge", ($rootScope, ArrayManipulation, Http, Cast, Modules, Toast) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/shared/status-badge/status-badge.html",
    scope: {
      bindModel: "=ngModel",
      statusChangingRequiredModules: "=",
      statusOptionsToBeHide: "<",
      onChange: "=",
      resource: "@"
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      if ($scope.bindModel==$rootScope._id) {
        $scope.active = true;
      }

    }
  }
});

// statusBadge.html directive 
<span ng-show="active">
  Active
</span>

// parent.js 
$scope._id = "123";

// app.js 
$rootScope._id = "123";

// parent.html 
<status-badge ng-model="_id"></status-badge>
```

Now when data is synchronomous the "Active" will be displayed, since its getting 
provided by initialization.

However, when working async - like receiving the data from the remote server, 
I have to include ng if, like that:

```
// app.js 
setTimeout(function () {
  $scope._id = "123";
}, 10);

// parent.html
// notice the ng-if
<status-badge ng-model="_id" ng-if="_id"></status-badge>
```

If I dont provide with the above ng-if, the directive configuation will be inited 
without the actual data.

Front end, later, will have the data, since as I mentined in the begining - AngularJS 
binds two way data, but only to HTML files.

Now I know I can put a watcher in the JS file, like this :

```
// statusBadge.js directive
app.directive("statusBadge", ($rootScope, ArrayManipulation, Http, Cast, Modules, Toast) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/shared/status-badge/status-badge.html",
    scope: {
      bindModel: "=ngModel",
      statusChangingRequiredModules: "=",
      statusOptionsToBeHide: "<",
      onChange: "=",
      resource: "@"
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      $scope.$watch("bindModel", function() {
        if ($scope.bindModel==$rootScope._id) {
          $scope.active = true;
        }
      }, true);

    }
  }
});
```

However this can be tidy to so everytime, and sometimes the list of the watchers is long:

```
// almost all of them are two way data binding, but resource and statusOptionsToBeHide
scope: {
  bindModel: "=ngModel",
  statusChangingRequiredModules: "=",
  statusOptionsToBeHide: "<",
  onChange: "=",
  resource: "@"
}
```

So what is the solution for this, or the best practice or just the preferred way of working?

Should I add the ng-if in each time its changed, and every time make it false - which can cause a bad UI - since the whole list, or component is going to be refreshed on each change - looks awful.

Should I put tons of watchers?

OR that is there any good solution for this?

Note that I have seen this question in Stack: 
[$watch'ing for data changes in an Angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980896/watching-for-data-changes-in-an-angular-directive)

However they tell there that it should be a watcher in there, but I need a "multiple" watcher.

Comment: angularjs component has $onChanges method :huh:

Comment: And directives not? :)

Comment: do not know :P -- after components were introduced, there is no sense to have directives with isolated scope

Comment: Can you post an answer and code please?